# Apache2 | 2 Domains with 1 IP | SSL Configuration 1x normal 1x Wildcard

Tags: ssl, apache2, subdomain

I have 2 Domains. `domain2.io` (2 Subdomains) with `Wildcard SSL` and `domain1.de` with a `normal SSL`. 
My Problem is that `domain2.io` somehow is using the SSL from the `domain1.de`.  What did I wrong? Here is my configuration:

000-default.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain1.de
        ServerAlias www.domain1.de
        Redirect / https://www.domain1.de/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain2.io
        ServerAlias www.domain2.io
        Redirect / https://domain2.io/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName service.domain2.io
        ServerAlias www.service.domain2.io
        Redirect / https://service.domain2.io
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName webapp.domain2.io
        ServerAlias www.webapp.domain2.io
        Redirect / https://webapp.domain2.io
</VirtualHost>
```

And here my 000-default-ssl.conf:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:443

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName domain1.de
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps/domain1/new/
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined.
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/domain1/domain1.de.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain1/domain1.de.key
        </VirtualHost>

        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName domain2.io
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/websites/domain2/webapp/
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined.
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/domain2/domain2.io.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain2/domain2.io.key
        </VirtualHost>

        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName service.domain2.io
                ServerAlias www.service.domain2.io
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/websites/domain2/backend/
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined.
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/domain2/domain2.io.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain2/domain2.io.key
        </VirtualHost>

        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName webapp.domain2.io
                ServerAlias www.webapp.domain2.io
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps/domain2/
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined.
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/domain2/domain2.io.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain2/domain2.io.key
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcart cert would not work, because it is for *.domain2.io - so it will not match domain2.io.
So you need a separate cert for domain2.io - or use www.domain2.io.

Should be no problem when using let's encrypt certs to get another one.

Comment: Ah thought it would recognize domain2.io as main domain and all *.domain2 as subdomains. Didnt know it only works for *.domain2. Ill try that with www.domain2.com and tell you the results

Comment: No it would not, because "its pattern matching" - "no dot" within domain2.io ;-) The same goes for host.subdomain.domain.tld - which requires a wildcard cert for *.subdomain.domain.tld, so that *.domain.tld would also not work - only for subdomain.domain.tld, but not for it's hosts.

Comment: wow. Changing my ServerName to www.domain2.io worked. Now all domains have their right SSL Cert. Maybe add this to your answer so others will know what I did. Thanks